# Managing Multi platform Application In-App Purchases

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am developing an App with Flutter and Firebase as backend. Here in the app, I want to use to the In-App purchases with trial for a month and then monthly or yearly Subscription on both iOS and Android Platforms.

Can anyone suggest the better way to work with the scenario like this?

The way I know is to upload the receipt from both platforms on server for verification from corresponding Store (we can verify receipts on App end as well for first time) and update the User node with In-App purchase related info. Then we can Schedule a cron to verify In-app purchase day before (basically two days i.e Day before and on Expiration day if not updated) the subscription get over.

And how we can manage it with Firebase only without cost for additional server to put the logic files to verify the In-App Purchases?

Thanks

Comment: What payment option(s) are you supporting?

Comment: no Payment methods basically, Its In-App Purchase for each platform @ChristilynArjona

Comment: @ChristilynArjona In need to use platform specific In-app Purchase only. No additional payment methods

Comment: @ChristilynArjona any suggestion? Help will be appreciated.